# How to install a specific version of Aerospike using Vagrant

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

I am following the steps in https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac/
to download Aerospike. However, by default I get the latest version of Aerospike (4.5.3) and I want to have the 3.7.5 version.

Any leads on how to do that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to run 3.7.5, that version is almost 4 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vagrant image used is a centos6 machine. You can easily download any available versions and install on your vagrant vm.

Here are the steps to remove the old installation and install a version:

1) Select your version for RHEL/Centos6/el6:

https://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/

for example 4.7.0.2

https://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/4.7.0.2/aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6.tgz

verify release notes:
https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html

2) Login to the running vagrant:

```
vagrant ssh
```

3) Modify your resolv.conf to use a public DNS server:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf'
```

4) Get the new image:

```
wget https://www.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-server-community/4.7.0.2/aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6.tgz
```

5) Untar and uncompress:

```
tar xvf aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6.tgz
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/SHA256SUMS
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/aerospike-tools-3.21.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/LICENSE
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/asinstall
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/dep-check
```

6) remove the old installed binary:

```
sudo rpm -e aerospike-server-community
```

7) install the new binary:

```
cd aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-el6/

sudo rpm -ivh aerospike-server-community-4.7.0.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```